# Can 2 gearboxes for the same engine but different codes be compatible?

Tags: vw, transmission, manual-transmission, golf

I need to change my gearbox. I own a VW Golf 6 from 2009, 1.4 TSI, 122 HP, engine code CAXA. The gearbox code is LHY.

I found at a scrap yard a gearbox from an identical car (even the same engine code), but with a different code: MCB.

Are the 2 gearboxes compatible, given the fact that the engines are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gearbox will physically bolt to the engine and the car.

The difference comes to the gear ratios, gear linkage and driveshaft flanges.

I don't know about your specific codes but if it is coming out of a similar size and and weight vehicle which it is the ratios will be fine. Check the gear linkage and make sure the lever lengths, ball joint size etc are the same (or swap yours over). Also look at the drive shaft flanges, measure the diameter and distance from the face to the oil seal.

If those three are the same then it will fit and work no problem